# What is the difference between an intentFilter category and an intentfilter action in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, filter, action, categories

I am confused about intent filters. Could someone explain to me what the difference between an Action and a Category is?

Answer (score 1):

ACTION: defines the action the Intent wants to do, VIEW, PICK, etc.

CATEGORY: points to a category attached to the Intent.